# Xamarin: How to include folder of audio files into app and read folder content

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was trying to implement a very simple app for ios/android which scans a folder I created in the shared project folder rendering a ListView showing the folders inside.

But I already fail on including that folder into the application environment in a way so I can easily scan the content of that folder.

What is the best way of having a folder with a list of subfolders and text files inside? What I wanna do is run something like Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.txt"), which i expect to get a list of paths looking like "subpath/01.txt", "subpath2/01.txt".

Using the EmbeddedResoure option for the text file makes it impossible to scan the folder because I want the app to dynamically read in the entire folder recursively instead of predefining every single file in order to fetch it with some assembly stream method.

I set the files to Build Action = None and Copy to output ... = Copy if newer, then use the following code:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
```

But that gives me an empty array.

Comment: You could include those files in a iOS folder within the app bundle and mark them as bundle resources, on Android you could use Assets or Resources/raw.

Comment: @SushiHangover: does that mean there is no way to include them in the shared project and use in both iOS and Android?